# Creating a new module with DXL for DOORS 9

Tags: ibm-doors

The script I have works for previous versions of DOORS, but breaks for DOORS 9.5. Specifically when I'm trying to create a new module by using:

> create(string name, string desc, int mapping [,bool display])

This is the error I'm receiving:

> create module failed: No access to create item

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a variable in there,

```
create(string name, string desc, string prefix, int absno [,bool display])
```

I am using 9.3.0.5 but I think it's the same for 9.5. Also I would double check that you have write access to the folder you are in and that you are not using the name of a module that already exists (deleted modules count). Try `F5` to refresh and make sure one didn't get created already.

Comment: Actually when I just ran your command in a test environment, it created a link module. My guess is you don't have access to the folder you are in. Also if you are not trying to create a link module I think you need the extra variable for prefix (but you can leave it blank with `""`).

Answer (score 0):

When I run the following code in DOORS v9.5,

```
Module lnkmod = create("Link Module", "This is a link module.", manyToMany, true)
```

it works and I get a new link module. Your error points to an access rights problem, as Steve suggested.